# Practical algorithm for finding a path of length $k$ of minimum total weight in graph?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science

> Practical algorithm for finding a path of length $k$ of minimum total weight in graph?

I want to find a path $v_1 \rightarrow v_2 \rightarrow \ldots \rightarrow v_k$ such that all $v_i$'s are distinct and the sum of the distances on the edges is minimized.

My question is twofold.

Does the above problem have a formal name like TSP or Hamiltonian path problem?

What are the efficient algorithms for solving this problem? I look for algorithms that is "easily" implemented modern programming languages.

Indeed, an algorithm is depth-first search from each vertex, stopping when encountered a path of length $k$?

Comment: Just to make sure that I understand - are you asking for the "least efficient" path of length $k$? The path of length $k$ between two points that are the smallest distance apart? In the cycle $C_6$, if we consider $k=5$, then any two adjacent points are distance 1 apart, but have a path of length $5$ between them (going the "long way" around the cycle)...

Comment: I want to find a path $v_1 \rightarrow v_2 \rightarrow v_3$ such that all $v_i$'s are distinct and the sum of the distances on the edges is minimized :-)

Comment: [This](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-path-exactly-k-edges-directed-weighted-graph/) may help, but I'm guessing that there is no magic here, that you have to test each starting vertex independently.

Comment: @rogerl The trouble is that the dynamic programming algorithm in your link doesn't require all vertices in a path to be distinct as the OP requested and it's unclear if it can be modified to enforce that requirement. The other algorithm would work but it is very slow.

Comment: @Qudit nice solution (+1), but I'm not sure that $|V|^2$ constitutes "efficient"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem does not have a standard name as far as I know.  However, it is NP-hard so there is no general algorithm.  Let us define the *length* of a path to be the number of edges that it contains and the *cost* of a path to be the sum of the weights of those edges.

To see that the problem is NP-hard observe that a graph $G$ on $n$ vertices contains a Hamiltonian path if and only if it contains a path of length $n - 1$ in which all vertices are distinct.  If any such paths exist, then one of them has minimal cost.  Thus, the Hamiltonian path problem reduces to your problem for length $k = n - 1$.

Edit: This answer previously gave an algorithm that was completely incorrect.  See the comments and revision history.

Comment: What does “n” denote in complexity? Why not just write “|V|”?

Comment: @Shuzheng No particular reason.  I wrote $n$ out of habit but it is more consistent to use $|V|$ for both.

Comment: The all-pairs shortest path algorithm is pretty “hard” to implement, right? It is not a short implementation, or?

Comment: @Shuzheng Floyd-Warshall is 11 lines on Wikipedia.  Implement that one if you don't mind something a little slower that's easy to implement.

Comment: Nice, have you made the above algorithm yourself? Or can I find it in some book?

Comment: @Shuzheng I created it for this problem.  It's entirely possible that it's been found before but I'm not aware of any reference.

Comment: Does the algorithm work for both directed and undirected graphs? May the graphs have self-loops? May they both be sparse and dense? Any restrictions?

Comment: @Shuzheng See the article I linked.

Comment: I don't think your correctness proof is correct. You assume that $P'$ is also a path from $u,v$ (like $P^*$). You need to say that $P'$ is a path from $u',v'$ of cost strictly less than $P^*$, i.e., $P' < P^*$. But then $P'$ would also be a shortest path (of length $k-1$), and so $P^* \le P'$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @Shuzheng It's fine as is.  I never assumed that $P^*$ is a path between $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Doesn't your algorithm only finds a shortest path of length $k-1$, if such path is actually a shortest path between two vertices. Suppose no path of length $k-1$ is shortest, then this algorithm will not find the shortest $k-1$ path in the graph, right?

Comment: @Shizheng If there is a path of length $k - 1$ then some path of length $k - 1$ has minimal cost.

Comment: Yes, but your method won’t find it? You put all shortest paths between vertices in a set. Then you filter from this set those of length $k-1$. So, if no shortest paths of length $k-1$ exist between vertices in the graph, then your method won’t find the shortest of the paths of length $k-1$? Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @Shuzheng No, in fact the whole algorithm is completely wrong.  Actually, I think your problem is unfortunately NP-hard.  I will fix the answer in a moment.